# CSS vertical align button in div not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

My CSS button is not vertical aligning at the bottom of the div, I've got the following code:

```
<div id="spacebuttons" align="right" style="height: 150px; width:920px; background-color:#6F0; display: inline-block; float:left; vertical-align:bottom">
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/cspace/customerspace.php">
    <img src="images/FontAwesome_f007(0)_32.png" alt="customer space" width="32" height="32" border="0" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick="window.location.href('http://www.domain.com/cspace/customerspace.php')">Customer  Space</button>
    </a>
```

What am I doing wrong?[image: css vertical-align]

Comment: Can create jsfiddle for this? so we can tell whats wrong.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) pl. !

Comment: Why wrapping button link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5318s1a5/

Comment: dmitriy I had to wrap the button link for IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This I have added some style for you but i don't know about you exact Output

```css
#spacebuttons {
    height: 150px;
    width:96%; 
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: #6F0; 
    float:left; 
}
#spacebuttons a {
    line-height: 32px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
#spacebuttons a img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="spacebuttons">
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/cspace/customerspace.php">
    <img src="images/FontAwesome_f007(0)_32.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" border="0" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick="window.location.href('http://www.domain.com/cspace/customerspace.php')">Customer  Space</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `line-height` for your anchor tag as same as your div height like below.

```
 <a href="http://www.domain.com/cspace/customerspace.php" style="line-height:150px;">
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tay2baL1/)